# Dojo form validating specific items in form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, dijit.form

I have a **dojo** form which uses the **dojo form wizard**. The form has one  tag. Within the form tag is a **dojo.wizard.Wizard**. It is a requirement that the wizard be inside a form tag. Within the Wizard is several wizard panes.

On each wizard pane i have form fields. I am preforming validation by calling a method on the wizard pane **passFunction**. However for the **dojo validation** to work i must get the children elements on the form and call the validate method against the form. This validates the entire form.

This is not practical for what i want to do since the first pane has n form elements, the second pane has *n* elements. When the validate function is called from the **passFunction** on the first pane it validates elements on other panes which are inaccessible yet.

How can i specify items to be validated for the form? I would like to validate only items on the first pane then move to the second pane and validate only those items. Under is my code structure:

**Jsp**

```
<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="myForm" />
 <div data-dojo-type="dojox.widget.Wizard" data-dojo-props="style: 'height:450px; width: 600px'">

   <div dojoType="dojox.widget.WizardPane" id="page1" passFunction="validatePage1" >

       <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="
            regExp: '[\\w]+',
            required: true,
            invalidMessage: 'First Name Required !'" id="fnameTextBox" title="First Name" placeholder="Your First Name" />
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="
            regExp: '[\\w]+',
            required: true,
            invalidMessage: 'Last Name Required !'" id="lnameTextBox" title="Last Name" placeholder="Your Last Name" />

   </div>

 <div dojoType="dojox.widget.WizardPane" id="page2" passFunction="validatePage2" >

       <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="
            regExp: '[\\w]+',
            required: true,
            invalidMessage: 'Age Is Required !'" id="ageTextBox" title="Age" placeholder="Your Age" />
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="
            regExp: '[\\w]+',
            required: true,
            invalidMessage: 'Phone Number Required '" id="phoneTextBox" title="Phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number" />

   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

In validatePage1 i would only like to validate surname and firstname fields and once that is completed when i move to the second page i would like to validate age and phone number. I am only checking for nulls presently.

**Javascript**

```
dojo.require("dijit/form/Form");
dojo.require("dijit/form/Button");
dojo.require("dijit/form/ValidationTextBox");
dojo.require("dijit/Tooltip");

function validatePage1(){      

        var myform = dijit.byId('myForm');
        myform.connectChildren();
        myform.validate();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to know what are the fields to be checked. So we can add a class to those fields for this purpose. Lets call it "chkThisField".

```
//a function to validate the given field
var highlight = function(widget){
   if(!widget.validate) return true;
   widget._hasBeenBlurred = true;
   widget.validate();
};

var fields = dojo.query(".chkThisField"); 
//above line is to get array of all fields with the "chkThisField" class
fields.forEach(function(fld){
  var widget = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(fld);
  highlight(widget);
});
```

So now,with the help of class selector, we have successfully validated specific fields only.

Comment: can you assist with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253170/dojo-using-deferred-functions-to-get-data-in-ajax-callback-function